# php foreach multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach, associative-array

I have multidimensional associative array as follows

```
  sr_array=>
    array (size=18)
  0 => string 'Shop' (length=4)
  1 => string 'Papu Kushwaha' (length=13)
  2 => string 'Jitendra Shukla' (length=15)
  3 => string 'Satish' (length=6)
  4 => string 'Pradeep' (length=7)
  5 => string 'Papu Khan' (length=9)
  6 => string 'Bharat' (length=6)
  7 => string 'Manoj Pandey' (length=12)
  8 => string 'select' (length=6)
  'Shop' => 
    array (size=9)
      'count_auto' => int 60
      'count_indus' => int 4
      'count_mc' => int 100
      'count_inverter' => int 10
      'count_in_bat' => int 40
      'total_credit' => int 191850
      'sale_value' => int 1351755
      'total_disc' => float 22377.38
      'perc_disc' => float 1.66
```

and so on....

now i want print them in table format I have used following code for output

```
echo"<table border=1>";
            echo"<tr>";
            echo"<th></th>";


        for($i=0; $i < count($sr_array)/2; $i++){
            $current_sr = $sr_array[$i];
            echo"<th>{$current_sr}</th>";
        }
        echo"</tr>";

        $keys = array_keys($sr_array);

        for($i=0; $i < count($sr_array)/2; $i++){
            $current_sr = $sr_array[$i];
            echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td></td>";

            foreach($sr_array as $key => $var){
                 foreach($var as $x => $y)
                    echo"<td>{$y["count_auto"]}</td>";
             }

            echo"</tr>";
        }
```

Please help me to get out as

```
-------------------------------------
|           |Shop    |xyz      |abc   |
-------------------------------------
count_auto  |60      |75       | 85   |
-------------------------------------
count_indus | 25     | 74      |15    |
--------------------------------------
count_mc    |  55    | 212     | 15   |
-------------------------------------
```

and so on

I am getting error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental issue here is that when you are iterating over sr_array, you are assuming that the values are also arrays. This is not the case for index 0 through 8 (from what I can tell). This would explain the immediate issue.

Ideally, the structure of your array is consistent (ideally, a two-dimensional array of rows, each containing a set of fields), then a simple nested loop will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution with a combination of `for()`/`foreach()` and looped iteration.

Also, consider a transposed html table with data as the columns and descriptives as rows. To do otherwise requires complex iteration as the array items are not aligned to the html markup.

```
echo "\n<table>\n";

$i = 0;
echo "\n<tr>\n";
echo "\n<th></th>\n";
foreach($sr_array as $item) {                 
    echo "<th>". array_keys($item)[$i] ."</th>\n";
    $i++;
}
echo "</tr>\n";

$j=0;
foreach($sr_array as $item) {

    echo "\n<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>" . array_keys($sr_array)[$j] . "</td>\n";
            foreach($item as $key => $value)
            {
                echo "<td>". $value . "</td>\n";
            }
    echo "</tr>\n";
    $j++;
}
echo "\n</table>\n";
```

And output as below (I repeat your posted data for example):

```
               count_auto   count_indus count_mc count_inverter     count_in_bat total_credit sale_value total_disc perc_disc
Shop            60          4   100     10  40  191850  1351755     22377.38    1.66
Papu Kushwaha   60          4   100     10  40  191850  1351755     22377.38    1.66
Jitendra Shukla 60          4   100     10  40  191850  1351755     22377.38    1.66
Satish          60          4   100     10  40  191850  1351755     22377.38    1.66
Pradeep         60          4   100     10  40  191850  1351755     22377.38    1.66
Papu Khan       60          4   100     10  40  191850  1351755     22377.38    1.66
Bharat          60          4   100     10  40  191850  1351755     22377.38    1.66
Manoj Pandey    60          4   100     10  40  191850  1351755     22377.38    1.66
select          60          4   100     10  40  191850  1351755     22377.38    1.66
```

Comment: Sorry taking so much time to reply. I run your code its showing few errors please guide me. First

 foreach($sr_array as $item) {                 
    echo "<th>". array_keys($item)[$i] ."</th>\n";
    $i++;
}
When I run above code loop runs 18 time were i have 9 items in my array.

Second its shows error in  

foreach($item as $key => $value)
            {
                echo "<td>". $value . "</td>\n";
            }

Comment: Our `sr_array` may be defined differently. I used named keys: `$sr_array['Shop']['count_auto'] = 60 ...` Please edit your post in how you define the array (just a few first items).